# Javascript how to make functions/variables globally available

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, soundcloud, document-ready

I am a beginner and made an custom SoundCloud Player, but the javascript is not very good because I couldn't get the variables and functions to get global. At the moment I have in some functions the same code as in another function to calculate a variable like the current time of the music in the player. especially for the `currenttime` I have 2 timers running and I need one more, too. An easy way to solve this would be to make variables like the current second globally available.

I've tried to put all the code in a `document.ready` or use return values but it didn't work.

**Here is my code:**

```
function toggle() {
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
    widget.isPaused(function(boolean){
        widget.toggle();
        playing = boolean;
        if(playing == true)
        {
            playtoggle.className ="";
            playtoggle.className ="play";
        }
        else if(playing == false)
        {
            playtoggle.className ="";
            playtoggle.className ="pause";
        }
    });
}
function refresher()
{
    setInterval(function(){timer()},10);

    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));

    widget.getDuration(function(duration){
        endtime = Math.round(duration/1000);
        var minute = Math.floor((endtime / 100) * 100 / 60);
        var sekunde = Math.round(endtime  - (minute * 60));
        if(sekunde<10)
        {
            document.getElementById('endtime').innerHTML = " "+ minute + ":0" + sekunde;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('endtime').innerHTML = " "+ minute + ":" + sekunde;
        }
    });  

}
function timer() {
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));

    widget.getCurrentSound(function(music){
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = music.title;
    })  

    widget.getPosition(function(position){
        currenttime = Math.round(position/1000);
        currentminute = Math.floor((currenttime /100) * 100 / 60);
        currentsek = Math.round(currenttime - (currentminute * 60));
        if(currentsek < 10)
        {
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = currentminute + ":0" + currentsek;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = currentminute + ":" + currentsek;
        }

        widget.getDuration(function(duration){
            endtime = Math.round(duration/1000);
            minute = Math.floor((endtime / 100) * 100 / 60);
            sekunde = Math.round(endtime  - (minute * 60));

            var pWidth = $('#gutter').width();
            var seekToposition = (position / duration)*pWidth;
            $('#seekTo').css('left', seekToposition-15+"px");
            $('#progress').css('width', seekToposition+"px");
        });

        if(currentminute == minute && currentsek == sekunde)
        {
            playtoggle.className="";
            playtoggle.className="pause";
        }
    });
}
function seekTo() {
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));

    var pWidth = $('#gutter').width();
    $('#gutter').click(function(e){
        var scrub = (e.pageX);
        $('#seekTo').css('left', scrub+"px");
        $('#progress').css('width', scrub+"px");
        widget.seekTo((scrub)/pWidth*311498);
    });
}
function keyfunction(e){
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));
    switch(e.keyCode){
      case 32:
        widget.isPaused(function(boolean){
            widget.toggle();
            playing = boolean;
            if(playing == true)
            {
                playtoggle.className ="";
                playtoggle.className ="play";
            }
            else if(playing == false)
            {
                playtoggle.className ="";
                playtoggle.className ="pause";
            }
        });
      break;
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dvv7P/)

On my computer it runs but I want to save some code by doing the variables make global.

Comment: its only for testing. At the end there will be another music. And after houres of testing this music sucks :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript there is always a scope for a variable, so in theory there is no such as "global" variable (like `static` in other languages for example).

But you can define anything on the `window` object (or in the root level of your code), which is accessible anywhere.

For example

```
window.myVariable = 4;
function alertMyVariable() {
  alert(window.myVariable); // alerts 4;
}
```

or the following has the same semantics:

```
var myVariable = 4;
function alertMyVariable() {
  alert(myVariable); // alerts 4;
}
```

But note that with the latter you have a potential danger of overriding that variable with a local one:

```
var myVariable = 4;
function alertMyVariable() {
  var myVariable = 6;
  alert(myVariable); // alerts 6!;
}
```

so it's probably better to qualify it with `window`.

Here is a [DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8kE3/) for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Interesting. didn know that. I hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myvariable;

function myFunction() {
  myvariable = 1;
}



function myFunction2() {
  if (myvariable == 1)
    // something
}
```